# Mapserver hide OGR exception

Tags: mapserver, ogr, mysql

I use mapserver 7.0.2 to display Points which are taken from a MYSQL-database.
If the the SQL-statement fails (for example the database can't be reached) the mapserver gives out an OGR error-message, revealing the entire SQL-statement including user and password.

Example:

```
msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named '....'. msOGRFileNextShape(): OGR error. MySQL connect failed for: .....,user=.....,password=....,host=....,port=...,tables=..... Access denied for user '........' (using password: YES)
```

Is there a way to disable these exceptions?
I already tried the msencrypt feature to encrypt the password, but it does not affect the exception text.

This shows how i connect to the DB in the mapfile:

```
 CONNECTION "<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name='....'>
        <SrcDataSource>MYSQL:....,user=....,password=....,host=....,port=....,tables=....</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL>
        SELECT .... FROM .... 
        WHERE ....
        </SrcSQL> 
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding='PointFromColumns' x='....' y='....'/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    </OGRVRTDataSource>"
```

I have these problems on my CentOS installation.
I just checked if this problem also occurs on MS4W and here its a bit different:

```
msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named '....'. msOGRFileNextShape(): OGR error. MySQL connect failed for: geobase,user=root,password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

It still prints the user (when with problem server / login) and the SQL-Statement (when the statement fails) but on ms4w it masks the password with XXXXXXXXX... which is alot better than printing it.

Comment: Is that error message visible also for users or only for the MapServer administrator?

Comment: It is visible to all users which is a problem, instead of the image it gives back the error (if the statement fails).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in Mapserver-7.0.3 and backported to other versions (6.0.5, 6.2.3, 6.4.4).  Looks like Kain's question was taken as a bug report which was subsequently fixed.  See [OGR error messages too verbose](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/pull/5356) .

Comment: Thx, i would recommend version 7.0.4 as version 7.0.3 fired a similar error message.